# Duplicate dependencies when installing Scarlet

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, websocket, client

In order to get the websocket module I install these two dependencies:

```
 implementation 'com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.9'
 implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-websocket-okhttp:0.1.9"
```

But when I build my app, I get this error:

```
Duplicate class com.tinder.scarlet.Deserialization found in modules scarlet-core-0.1.9.jar (com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-core:0.1.9) and scarlet-core-0.1.9.jar (com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-core:0.1.9)
... bunch of other duplicates
```

If I remove either one, then I can't use the packages because I need both dependencies.

This is my connection class:

```
object Connection {
    fun connect() {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()


        val scarletInstance = Scarlet.Builder()
            .webSocketFactory(okHttpClient.newWebSocketFactory("ws://url.."))
            .build()

        val messageService = scarletInstance.create<MessageService>()

        messageService.observeWebSocketEvent()
            .filter { it is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened<*> }
            .subscribe({
                Timber.d("connected to web socket")
            })

        messageService.observeText()
            .subscribe({ text ->
                Timber.d("Web socket message: $text")
            })
    }
}
```

The core dependency contains `com.tinder.scarlet.Scarlet` classes, and the websocket dependency contains `com.tinder.scarlet.websocket.okhttp.newWebSocketFactory` classes, and I can't have one without the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to install the 0.2.x branch:

I used these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.2.4'
implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-protocol-websocket-okhttp:0.2.4'
```

Both work with the current example code at the commit: https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/tree/45d97cc6d0de537872af789306765715978efecc

New Connection object:

```
object Connection {
    fun connect() {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()

        val protocol = OkHttpWebSocket(
            okHttpClient,
            OkHttpWebSocket.SimpleRequestFactory(
                { Request.Builder().url("ws://...").build() },
                { ShutdownReason.GRACEFUL }
            )
        )

       val configuration = Scarlet.Configuration()

       val messageService = Scarlet(protocol, configuration).create<MessageService>()


        messageService.observeWebSocketEvent()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({
                Timber.d("connected to web socket")
            })

        messageService.observeText()
            .subscribe({ text ->
                Timber.d("Web socket message: $text")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, for anyone coming here, this import statement may not work. See here if you have trouble: https://jitpack.io/#Tinder/Scarlet

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.9"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:websocket-okhttp:0.1.9"
```

without scarlet- prefix

Answer (score 1):

```
Duplicate class com.tinder.scarlet.Deserialization found in modules 
scarlet-core-0.1.9.jar (com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-core:0.1.9) 
and scarlet-core-0.1.9.jar (com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-core:0.1.9)
```

This is happening because of one dependency is from `com.tinder.scarlet` and another dependency is from `com.github.tinder.scarlet`.

`com.tinder.scarlet` - is their release version

`com.github.tinder.scarlet` - they are saying `We are working on a new version of Scarlet that supports other persistent connection protocols: ServerSentEvent, Socket IO, STOMP, and MQTT. It can be found on the 0.2.x branch`

I tried a lot to resolve it by excluding it from dependency in gradle file but it didn't work.

So, finally what I did was, `implementation 'com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.9'` in gradle file and copy-pasted their files present in `websocket`, `rxFactory` and `gsonFactory` in my project. 
I know it's not the recommended way, but it completed my job.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "com.github.tinder.scarlet" that is the previous groupId for scarlet lib.

Now scarlet lib moved to maven central and you should use "com.tinder.scarlet" as groupId.

The "com.github.tinder.scarlet" is grouped for under development scarlet packages so you shouldn't use it cause it's not stable.
The "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.2.4" is under development yet so dont use it.

You can find other artifacts for scarlet lib in [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.tinder.scarlet)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the version 2 and it is working. Import this on your gradle :)

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}

implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.2.4'
implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-protocol-websocket-okhttp:0.2.4'
implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-stream-adapter-rxjava2:0.2.4"
implementation "com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-message-adapter-moshi:0.2.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

By defining the dependencies like in this [github issue](https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/issues/96) I got it to work without errors:

```
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:$libVersions.scarlet"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:websocket-okhttp:$libVersions.scarlet"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:lifecycle-android:$libVersions.scarlet"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:message-adapter-gson:$libVersions.scarlet"
implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:stream-adapter rxjava2:$libVersions.scarlet"

libVersions = [
        scarlet: '0.1.9'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these dependencies and it worked flawlessly

```
implementation group: 'com.tinder.scarlet', name: 'scarlet', version: '0.1.10'
implementation group: 'com.tinder.scarlet', name: 'message-adapter-moshi', version: '0.1.10'
```